# Error installing kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am using `pip install` to install kivy on windows 10. I keep getting an error in the command prompt that states:

> (could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from
>   versions: ) no matching distribution found for pywin32 (from
>   pypiwin32)

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Also i am using python 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing pypiwin32:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32

Then retry installing kivy, if that doesn't work then install pywin32: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32 and try again.

Comment: I am using python 34. I do not see a version for that to install. Should i change my version of python to 36 being the kivy documentation has a warning for python 35

Comment: Well I would recommend you do that, but it's possible to install them from source as well. Head to the github repertories for details: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue (error)
it couldn't find any version that satisfies the python interpreter , any version of python that Pywin32 doesn't support
type in the console (cmd) :  pip install pypiwin32==219 
this version 219 nearly supports all the versions of python (not all of them !)
and if still not worked do this : choose on of these versions of python and install it then it will work ! 
2.7.X
3.1.X
3.2.X
3.3.X
3.4.X
3.5.X
notice that this version doesn't support 3.6 , anyway good luck with your programming see you again boys !